# How to fix "The requested app is not available or doesn't exist." in Testflight

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

When I Archive and upload to app store connect to test in TestFlight. It cannot download app and show

> Could not install [App] The requested app is not available or doesn't exist.

and When I look at previous Builds. It show same message in all build version.

It happen after renew apple development programs.

Comment: Experiencing same issue, Tried removing and adding the testers, tried changing Certificates and profiles (ios,Apple Distribution). Changed build number for every build, Tried changing Device Location. Nothing worked. I have made sure that the apple ID's are correct.

Comment: I have the same problem since this weekend.

Comment: experiencing this issue as well. Sounds like it may be a bug on apple's end

Comment: I've got test users seeing the same issue too so it does look like it is Apple's side of things.

Comment: We've had the same issue since end of last week.  Not sure what the problem is.  Tried everything listed.  Can't even load on internal testers devices

Comment: I have some issue and I use Ionic&Capacitor.

Comment: @raykin were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In my case, my app has been removed from Appstore a few years ago. When I upgraded the code and tried to send it to Testflight, this happened. THE SOLUTION IS, make necessary changes in the app and release it into the Appstore again. when your app is successfully Launched, Your Testflight will be automatically restored.
When the app is removed from the store and is still "Not in sale", this happens.
Release the app and everything will be fine. If this does not work, contact apple support.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation. I haven't tried to release it to the App Store again yet though. Instead I contacted support. They said it's showing "removed from sale" rather than "developer removed from sale." But I am the one who removed it from sale some years ago when I realized it was no longer iOS compatible. Now I've upgraded it and want to test it with Testflight and it's saying the app doesn't exist when I enter the redeem code. Support has passed my question on to "App Review." Any thoughts (or prayers?). Thanks.

Comment: @DougLerner test ur app and release it to the store, don't worry...testflight will be restored after the app is released.

Answer (score 7):

Apple told me, that the problem is, that my app is currently in the state: `Removed from Sale`. I have to submit a new app build into review, to enable TestFlight builds again.

Comment: Figures that apple would not give a valid response. This was not the case for my apps but i couldn't wait on apple so i went ahead and deleted and rebuilt. When they reply to my support ticket they'll probably say the same thing, that its removed. Well yeah its removed. I removed it because it couldn't be downloaded!

Comment: Hmm, this is so strange.

Comment: My App State is now `Ready for Sale`, since I release a new version. Now TestFlight build also work again.

Answer (score 5):

We rebuilt our app and actually have it approved for sale - “ready for developer release” but still getting the same TestFlight error. Submitted a ticket to Apple and waiting on a response.

Update: had to release the app for sale for a few minutes and then remove from sale.  That fixed the TestFlight problem. Not ideal but at least we can use TestFlight again

Comment: That's interesting, please let us know, if something changes.

Comment: Same here. I emailed back and forth with the Apple, and in the end I only got the reply that the app could not be installed from Testflight (even though the Testflight builds got approved) because it had been removed from sale. So we submitted the half-ready app and got it approved, but this did not fix the problem. I spoke to the Apple support again, and this time got to talk to someone who actually seemed to understand the problem. They said they would get back to me, but never did. However, after a day or so the app could again be installed from Testflight. Fixed by them? Not sure...

Comment: In the end we released our app for 2 minutes and then took it off the store and since then TestFlight is working again. Basically it looks like if the status is removed for sale(by Apple) TestFlight will stop working.

Answer (score 1):

Same here. I'm on xCode 12.4 and all my certificates are valid but still getting that error and my users to.

Answer (score 1):

I did not submit my app, however it had a status of "Approved" next to a yellow icon on the TestFlight tab. The external testers that used the link were getting the error "The requested app is not available or doesn't exist.”

When I tried to add a tester by using an email address, there was a message saying "no builds available".

I solved the issue by clicking "notify testers" at which point the yellow icon changed to a green one and testers were able to install the app using the link.

Not sure if this is the "great user experience" Apple asks for in their app guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had a version removed from sale. I added a new version and new builds but impossible to resolve the issue.

I had to create a new application and upload my build for the new application to be able to make work the TestFlight.