# Why does TestFlight throw error: "Could not install..."

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, app-store-connect, testflight

After uploading the app [I can't install it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gjkmm.jpg). I get the following

```
error: "Could not install MY_APP_NAME. The requested app is not available or doesn't exist".
```

What might cause this issue and how can I fix it?

Things I tried:

- Rename the app
- Recreate certificate and provision profile
- Reinstall TestFlight on the device

From the device logs, I see the next TestFlight issue:

```
"Cannot get app record for BundleID MY_APP_BUNDLEID: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
```

I provided the correct bundle id, otherwise, I cannot be able to upload the app to TestFlight.

Comment: Does the app icon appear on your device?  If so, try deleting it and install it from TestFlight again. Try restarting your device

Comment: Icon doesn't appear. I also tried to reinstall TestFlight and reboot device but got same result

Comment: It could be a transitory error on apples server

Comment: I see this error for 5 days

Comment: Can you try on a different iOS device?  Can you invite another person and see if they have the same problem. You may need to raise a support request with apple developer support.

Comment: All internal testers have face this issue. I have already sent request to the TestFlight support but still haven't get an answer

Comment: Log a developer support ticket using one of your paid incidents. They will often credit it back to you if the problem is theirs

Comment: This question is already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66172052/how-to-fix-the-requested-app-is-not-available-or-doesnt-exist-in-testflight) hope it helps.

Comment: It is not my case. My app has never been released into the App Store. Anyway thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple support got back to me. A night later issue has gone. I don't have any details about it, it is just gone. Seems like it was an issue on TestFlight side.